# Python: How can I fully print out the first n keys and values of the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to print the keys and values with the values sorted from the largest to the smallest:

```
customer_dict = {3:30, 1:22, 2:22}
sorted_values = [30, 22, 22]
sorted_dict = {}

for i in sorted_values:
        for k in customer_dict.keys():
            if customer_dict[k] == i:
                sorted_dict[k] = customer_dict[k]
                break

for x in list(sorted_dict)[:3]:
    print(str(x) + ',' + str(sorted_dict[x]))
```

The answer I was expected is

```
3,30
1,22
2,22
```

But, it will only print out

```
3,30
1,22
```

But, if there are no duplicate values in the dictionary, it will print out the correct answer, so I'm wondering why this is happening. Can someone tell me where the code is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop stops at the first matched value. It does not find all of the matches for your value.

There's no need to create a separate dictionary. You can sort the items of the dictionary based on value in descending order, and then iterate over the result of that sorting process.

```py
customer_dict = {3:30, 1:22, 2:22}

for key, value in sorted(customer_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(f"{key},{value}")
```

This outputs:

```py
3,30
1,22
2,22
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed to remove the break. This code produces your desired example.

```
customer_dict = {3:30, 1:22, 2:22}
sorted_values = [30, 22, 22]
sorted_dict = {}

for i in sorted_values:
        for k in customer_dict.keys():
            if customer_dict[k] == i:
                sorted_dict[k] = customer_dict[k]
            


for x in list(sorted_dict)[:3]:
    print(str(x) + ',' + str(sorted_dict[x]))
```